# How to Select Current Date and/or Use System Variables or System Calls to Forward Information with Selenium in Python Like Dates and Name Formats

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

So I am trying to select the current date, or use a system call from Powershell or Linux/Mac to a system variable with the OS Module. I need help in understanding the best way about how to go about accomplishing this.

- Option 1. How can I select the Highlighted date within the Calendar
- Option 2. How can I use a System Variable that will format the date to what I desire

Preferably I like option 2 because the system variable will always be set by that of the computer. So I know that the date is always what I need and is current.

Here is a picture. 
[image]

Notice that today's highlighted portion is the 27th, which is today's date. 
However, I am thinking a system variable might be able to just format the date to what I want. 
In powershell I know the command is `Get-Date -UFormat %D`. However, I would like to know how to pass this off, I also think the XPATH I have is wrong.

```
# Select Current Date
# Set Variable for OS_DATE to be in Format MM/DD/YYYY
# For Powershell $(Get-Date -UFormat %D)
# //*[@id='createdTo']/option[text()='01/27/2020']
#element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
#                                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='createdTo']/option[text()='01/27/2020']")))
#element.click();
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am trying to input the date as always current in there, here is the source for the element that I need to update.

```
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="dateTo" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="dateTo" show-weeks="false" is-open="uploadedTo" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-change="changeUploadDate();" ng-keydown="dateInputKeyDown($event,'uploadedTo')" required="" name="createdTo" id="createdTo" style="">
```

Also here is the source code on [my Github Repository](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Collegeboard/TSI/collegboard_tsi_export.py)

I have been working on this a while now and have even taken some of the tips from the response I got from below. I finally figured out how to update the field. However, it is not overwriting the field. I am attaching the screenshot and the code that updates the field to showcase the overall issue.

[image]

Here is the code that got to input the date

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='createdTo']")))
element.send_keys(date);
```

Currently the code is commented out as the incorrect date prevents the file from downloading.

Comment: looks like you can just type it in...(sendKeys)  Format system date to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: I tried doing that and was using ```element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='createdTo']/option[text()='print(date)']")))
element.click();``` as the piece of code to handle that with date defined as the string format of today

Comment: ```element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                 EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='createdTo']/option[text()='print(date)']")))
element.click();``` doesn't seem to work with ```# System Variables
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")```

Comment: I was suggesting using sendKeys... something like: element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='createdTo'])); element.sendKeys("mm/dd/yyyy");

Comment: I tried to use the ```element.sendKeys``` method with no luck. Are you sure you don't mean ```element.send_keys```?

Comment: forgot about the python part... yeah I think you're right.

Comment: So I found out how to update the field. Awesome, however it is not overwriting the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this actually works for printing the date after I set a variable from within the code.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='createdTo']")))
element.send_keys(date);
```

The variable is obviously date, which is defined as

```
from datetime import date

# System Variables
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```