# How to Overwrite a Specific Field with Pre-existing Entry in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

So I am trying to overwrite a date field that I have to insert the current date so the data pull is always current. I currently have found the solution that overwrites the date field with Selenium Webdriver for Chrome and Python. However, the issue is that the date doesn't overwrite what is saved with the query. Here is the current code that sends the date.

```
# Select Current Date !!!NOTE ISSUE ON CURRENT DATE BEING SET!!!
# Set Variable for OS_DATE to be in Format MM/DD/YYYY
# For Powershell $(Get-Date -UFormat %D)
# //*[@id='createdTo']/option[text()='01/27/2020']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='createdTo']")))
element.send_keys(date);
```

You can see the full code [here](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Collegeboard/TSI/collegboard_tsi_export.py)
Here is a picture that showcases what I need:
[image]

Notice the **To** fields above the calendar. I need to write the current date by overwriting the date that is loaded with the query. The current code writes out the date as follows:
[image]

If you needs some more context there was another question I had asked in order to figure out how to send the current date to that field. We came up with the above code as mentioned. However, it doesn't overwrite the current loaded data. More context can be found with the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935423/how-to-select-current-date-and-or-use-system-variables-or-system-calls-to-forwar).

Comment: Why can't you just click on Clear and then Today buttons in the calendar?

Comment: Lol, I didn't even see that. I will give that a shot. I guess I was over complicating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion by @supputuri worked.

```
# Click Calendar Icon
# Element XPATH = //*[@id='collapseFour-1']/div/fieldset/import-date-select/div[1]/div[3]/div/span/button/i
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='collapseFour-1']/div/fieldset/import-date-select/div[1]/div[3]/div/span/button/i")))
element.click();

# Click Today Button on Calendar
# Element XPATH = //*[@id='collapseFour-1']/div/fieldset/import-date-select/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/span/button[1]
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='collapseFour-1']/div/fieldset/import-date-select/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/span/button[1]")))
element.click();
```

In essence, all I had to do was click on the Today Button.